# Integrating multiple dictionaries in python (big data)

Tags: python, memory, data-mining

I am working on a research project in big data mining. I have written the code currently to organize the data I have into a dictionary. However, The amount of data is so huge that while forming the dictionary, my computer runs out of memory. I need to periodically write my dictionary to main memory and create multiple dictionaries this way. I then need to compare the resulting multiple dictionaries, update the keys and values accordingly and store the whole thing in one big dictionary on disk. Any idea how I can do this in python? I need an api that can quickly write a dict to disk and then compare 2 dicts and update keys. I can actually write the code to compare 2 dicts, that's not a problem but I need to do it without running out of memory..

My dict looks like this:
"orange" : ["It is a fruit","It is very tasty",...]

Comment: Could you give us a sample of what your dictionary looks like? Are you just counting word occurrences?

Comment: In addition to what @HughBothwell has mentioned - where is the data coming from before it's organised (into a dict)?

Comment: I have a big database of twitter tweets.. See Stanford SNAP twitter data base..

Comment: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/#twitter

Comment: Well, is "SNAP" a requirement - or could you use something like MongoDB with a MapReduce to get enough to then use graph theory on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Hoffman: go for a relational database. Data-processing is a bit of an unusual task for a relational engine, but believe, it is a good compromise between easy of use/deployment and speed for large datasets.

I customarily use sqlite3, that comes just with Python, although more often I use it through [apsw](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/). The advantage of a relational engine like sqlite3 is that you can instruct it to do a lot of processing with your data through joins and updates, and it will take care of all the memory/disk swapping of data required, in quite a sensible manner. You can also use in-memory databases to hold small data which you need interacting with your big data, and have them linked through "ATTACH" statements. I have processed gigabytes this way.

Comment: Thanks.. Will look at databases!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a database such as PostgreSQL.

Comment: To start with, it will be able to handle much larger amounts of data than you can keep in memory. Any solution you create yourself will probably just be reimplementing features of a database, poorly.

Answer (score 0):

First thought - switch to 64-bit python and increase your computer's virtual memory settings ;-)

Second thought - once you have a large dictionary, you can sort on key and write it to file. Once all your data has been written, you can then iterate through all the files simultaneously, comparing and writing out the final data as you go.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "main memory" do you mean hard drive? There's only one memory system in a computer.

You can write Python data objects to files with the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html) module. I'm not sure if you can pickle more than one object into one file, but that should be immaterial.

```
import pickle

def dump_dict(dict, name):
    with open(name, 'wb') as file:
        return pickle.dump(file, dict)

def get_dict(name):
    with open(name, 'rb') as file:
        return pickle.load(file)

def get_key(key, *list_of_dicts):
    """The first argument is the key; any further args are interpreted as the names of
pickled dict files to check."""
    out = []
    for name in *list_of_dicts:
        with open(name, 'rb') as f:
            out.append(pickle.load(f).get(key)) # Add this dict's value, glossing over KeyErrors.
    return tuple(out)
```

You can surely figure out the rest and extend the functionality as necessary.

Comment: You can indeed pack as many objects into the same pickle file as you want.  Note that `cPickle` will be faster and `json` probably even faster than that if your objects are simple enough to be `json`ed.