# Combining multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary

I have a 12 GB file where each line is a JSON object of the form:

```
{
    "name": "abc", 
    "val1":500,
    "val2":30, 
    "val3":{
               "topic1":{
                            "val4":["abc","xyz"],
                            "val5":["asdf"]
                        }
           }
}
```

This is unfortunately the object structure and cannot be changed.

Suppose I have another line in this file:

```
{
    "name": "abc", 
    "val1":300,
    "val2":10, 
    "val3":{
               "topic2":{
                            "val4":["hello","world"],
                            "val5":["test"]
                        }
           }
}
```

I now need to merge the objects with the same name such that I get an object of the form:

```
{
    "name": "abc", 
    "val1":800,
    "val2":40, 
    "val3":{
               "topic1":{
                            "val4":["abc","xyz"],
                            "val5":["asdf"]
                        },
               "topic2":{
                            "val4":["hello","world"],
                            "val5":["test"]
                        }
           }
}
```

I am reading the file line by line and loading the JSON objects of each line in Python. So each line basically becomes a Python `dict()`. I then store this object in a MongoDB collection and if another object with the same name occurs in the file, I update the Mongo record such that it is merged as in the example above.

I am trying to follow the same approach as in [Integrating multiple dictionaries in python (big data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406085/integrating-multiple-dictionaries-in-python-big-data) but I'm using Mongodb instead to accommodate the object structure of some of the values. However, even for a sample 400 MB file, this is very slow.

Is there any way to do this better, maybe using some sort of parallel processing?

Comment: Not really that clear what you are asking. Is the data already imported into a MongoDB collection or not? In either case do you also mean that { "name": "abc", "val3": { "topic1": { "val4": ["efg","abc"] } } }` would combine with the above in a "val4" array to be `["abc","xyz",efg"]`? Or what?

Comment: At any rate, `mapReduce` is likely not a "great" option, considering that all output "must" be essentially {`"_id": "something", "value": "somethingElse" }` being that both the `_id` and `value` are mandatory as structure, no matter what they contain. So not the best option if your target is a new collection. But if you can live with that then okay.

Comment: No, the data is present in a file. I'm trying to combine the lines using MongoDB. The combination would be { "name": "abc", "val3": { "topic1":{ "val4":["abc","xyz"], "val5":["asdf"]} , "topic2":{"val4": ["efg", "abc"]}}} . Two objects with the same "name" field will not both have "topic1" (or any identical keys) in "val3".

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to combine multiple such objects with the same "name" field into one single object. To do this, I need to add the values where they are numerical, and combine the values where it is a nested object

Comment: Sorry but really clear as mud, and you should also be clear as to if it is your "intent" to ultimately store the information in MongoDB or not. If not and you are just thinking of using a "tool", then it's kind of like applying a chainsaw to cut a sandwich. Your examples of how objects will "merge" will be a lot clearer by including them in the body of your "question" with an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35619092/edit) there, rather than in comments.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear earlier. Could you tell me if it's more understandable now? The answer I've linked outlines the approach I'm trying to use but I'd like something that runs a bit faster. In the end, yes, all the information will be stored in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should help.

```
# not tested
import json

mydict = {}
with open(myfile,'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        myline = json.loads(line)
        if myline['name'] in mydict:
            mydict[myline['name']]['val1'] += myline['val1']
            mydict[myline['name']]['val2'] += myline['val2']
            mydict[myline['name']]['val3'] += [myline['val3']]
        else:
            mydict[myline['name']] = myline
            mydict[myline['name']]['val3'] = [myline['val3']]
```

Your question is really ambiguous, however, so this is my take on what you're trying to accomplish.

EDIT: I'm just concatenating the dictionaries, but you could implement more complicated merging logic in the section where the `.append(myline)` happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I didn't put my question across very well and this isn't what I'm looking for. I've edited my question to make it more understandable and I hope you will be able to help!

Comment: I made some edits to make this closer to what you need. My point was not to give you a piece of code that you could paste into your application. It was more to give you a scaffold that you could build into. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this approach initially, but the file is 12 GB and the dictionary (mydict, in your sample code), ran out of memory. I am trying to work with this but on smaller subsets of the file now